# animatorの遷移　着地判定について

Tags: unity2d

Unity初心者です。
2Dのアクションゲームを製作していますが、アニメーション遷移がうまくいかず困っています。
プレイヤーには今のところ(Idle) (Walk) (Jump)の三つのアニメーションを与えています。
しかし、（Jump)⇒（Walk)のトランジションがうまく動きません。
トランジションの設定は　velocity.yが０、かつ移動キーを押していればWalkをtrueにし、それ以外の二つはfalseにするというものです。これだと確かにジャンプした後にジャンプのアニメーションからwalkのアニメーションに代わってくれますが０．２秒あまりのラグが生まれてしまいます。どうすればこのラグをなくすことができるでしょうか？
不明な点がございましたら遠慮なくお申し付けください。回答お待ちしております。

Answer (score 0):

Animatorの遷移条件や詳細が正しく設定されているか見直してください。
IdleからWalkやJumpは即座に行われているのであれば、異なる設定が行われているはずです。

・Has Exit Timeのチェックを外す
・ブレンド時間などを0にする